# convert String to Date

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, simpledateformat

I want to convert the following string into Date type this way

```
Date dateToFormat = null;

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy"); 

String databaseDateAsString = "Wed May 11 16:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2011";

try {
    dateToFormat = formatter.parse(databaseDateAsString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot Parse Date:" + e);
}
```

But it is giving the following error:-

```
Cannot Parse Date:java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: 
        "Wed May 11 16:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2011"
```

Plz help how can I remove this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timezone format you are using is not allowed (read the javadocs). If possible, leave it out, parse the rest, setting the timezone in the dateFormat object itself

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date dateToFormat = null;

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy"); // zzzz yyyy");

    String databaseDateAsString = "Wed May 11 16:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2011";
    databaseDateAsString = "Wed May 11 16:30:00 2011";
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
    try {
        dateToFormat = formatter.parse(databaseDateAsString);
        System.out.println(dateToFormat);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Cannot Parse Date:" + e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on where you are, you may also need to specify the locale: new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.US)