# How can I format date?

Tags: android, date

I have dates in the format:

```
Wed Jan 18 08:50:04 Asia/Calcutta 2012
```

I want to depict just `18.01.2012`, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bit hacky because of the `Asia/Calcultta`

EDIT: Also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973692/convert-string-to-date)

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String date = "Wed Jan 18 08:50:04 Asia/Calcutta 2012";
        System.out.println(formatDate(date));
    }

    private static String formatDate(String date) throws Exception {
        String year = date.substring(date.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
        DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(String.format("dd.MM.%s",
                                                                  year));
        Date parse = sdf.parse(date);
        return fmt.format(parse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in your code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
            String strDate = sdfDate.format(date);
```

I tried that.